# How to validate a non number field with Yup?

Tags: yup

I have a field "company name" that must never contain any numeric characters at all and it should contain only string alphabetic characters, how to validate that with yup?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/yup#stringmatchesregex-regex-message-string--function-schema

I dont know anything about yup, but looking at the documentation, I would recommend `string.matches` then insert an alphabetic range into the regex. This would exclude numbers and symbols.

Comment: `match` with `regex` do the job, any other trick maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @IAmGroot

```
const schema = yup.object().shape({
  company_name: yup
      .string()
      .matches(/^[a-z]+$/, 'Only alphabetic characters allowed')
})
```